# Elasticsearch: Generate distribution tables from survey data

Tags: elasticsearch

I am storing survey data like this:

```
[  
  {  
    "userid":1,
    "answers":[  
      {  
        "key":"gender",
        "value":"male"
      },
      {  
        "key":"color",
        "value":"red"
      },
      {  
        "key":"vehicle",
        "value":"car"
      }
    ]
  },
  {  
    "userid":2,
    "answers":[  
      {  
        "key":"gender",
        "value":"female"
      },
      {  
        "key":"color",
        "value":"blue"
      },
      {  
        "key":"vehicle",
        "value":"bike"
      }
    ]
  },
  ......
]
```

The mapping is like:

```
"users" : {
    "properties" : {
        "userid" : {
            "type" : "long"
        },
        "answers" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
                "key" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
                },
                "value" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That means lots of users with lots of answers to different questions. I have to be flexible about what questions have been asked, so I chose the key/value style.

Now I want to find a query that will give me a distribution table on gender and color.
That means: A 2-dimensional table having gender as one axis and color as one axis showing me all possible terms in those fields.
I want to have a nice overview on how many women like the color red or how many men like blue and so on.

I tried a lot with nested filtered terms aggregations and did not succeed yet.

Any hints on how to build the aggregations query would be appreciated...

Comment: Can you sharing the mapping that you have for storing these user answers?

Comment: Updated the post with the mapping...

Comment: Am I correct in assuming this structure is inflexible since you are posting the question?  I mean storing the records like `{"userid": 1, "color": "red", "gender": "male"}` is not something you can switch over to?  It would make the aggregations and responses much nicer.

Answer (score 2):

You can check [scripted metric aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html)

in general it looks like this:

```
POST documents/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "distribution": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "initializations",
        "map_script": "build partial distribution for single document",
        "combine_script": "",
        "reduce_script": "summarize all partial distributions to final grid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

for your specific case I can suggest following query

```
POST test/example/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "distribution": {
      "scripted_metric": {
                "init_script" : "_agg['variants'] = [:]",
                "map_script" : "gender='';color=''; for (answer in _source.answers){ if(answer.key=='gender'){gender=answer.value};if(answer.key=='color'){color=answer.value}  }; if(gender!='' && color!=''){key=(gender+'-'+color); _agg['variants'][key]=_agg['variants'].get(key,0)+1}", 
                "combine_script" : "return _agg.variants",
                "reduce_script" : "result=[:]; for (a in _aggs) {a.each{k,v -> result[k]=result.get(k,0)+v} }; return result;"
            }
    }
  }
}
```

It will return something like this

```
{
  "took": 32,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 7,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "distribution": {
      "value": {
        "female-yelow": 4,
        "male-red": 1,
        "female-blue": 1,
        "male-blue": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

make sure you have [scripting enabled](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html) in server config

```
user:/etc/elasticsearch# head elasticsearch.yml 
script.inline: true
script.indexed: true
...
```

Comment: Thanks. Isn't there a non-scripted solution? I am looking for the official way, there has to be some way!

Comment: With you data structure the only thing I could think of is two nested aggs by value field. In this case all values should be unique (or you couldn't distinguish them) and it will need extra processing on app side.

Comment: How would that non-scripted solution look like? I don't want to use scripts, for security and performance reasons...